# Purging records on AS/400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, db2-400

I have to delete some records that are considered to be useless.

There is a address file and an order history file. In the company which has a consumer products, they get many product inquiries or start of sale that never becomes a sale.

Each inquiry gets a record in the address file, Customer number. In the order history file is same customer numn and a Suffix field. which is started at 000 and increments when there is new order. the bulk of the business is in fact a recurring  model.

A customer who has only '000' record (there could be multiple 000's), means they never bought anything we wish to purge them from these files.

I am thinking a simple RPG program but am also interested in just using SQL if that is possible or other methods.

At this stage, we would not actually be deleting but copying the proposed records for purging to an output file which will be reviewed and also would be stored in case a need to revert.

```
F Addressfile   IF  E

F OrderHistory  IF  E

**** create 2 output file clones but with altered name for now.

F Zaddressfile  O  E
F ZorderHistory O  E


                  *inlr    doweq *off
                           Read  Addressfile          lr
                  *inlr    ifeq *off
                           move  *off      Flg000
                           exsr  Chk000
                   Flg000  ifeq  *on
                           iter
                           else  exsr      purge
                           endif
                           endif
                           enddo

                   Chk000  begsr
```

**basically setll to a different logical on the orderhistory
                              and reade for a long as we have the matching customer number
                              and if there is a suffix not = 000 then we turn on the flag
                              and get out.

the purge subr will have to read thru again to get the records needed to purge from the orderhistory file by using the same customer number that would still be in the read of the address file. because i would not be sure what value has the subr, for customer and i dont want to store that.

then it would write to the new file incl the address file then we can iter read the next
customer in address file.

also we cannot assume that if someone did buy, they have a 001 maybe it got deleted over the years.

if we did, i could simply chain on that.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I could've sworn I'd read something showing speed gains of using SQL for batch processing versus native-IO, but don't know where it was now.  Anecdotally, I re-wrote a process here (along with some new indices, which are hard for native-IO to just 'use') that went from about 24 hours... to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorts of steps you have to do in RPG. This can be done in SQL a variety of simpler ways.  SQL is adept at processing and analyzing groups of records in an entire file all at once.

```
CREATE TABLE zaddresses AS
( SELECT *
    FROM addressFile
    WHERE cust IN (SELECT cust 
                     FROM orderHistory
                     GROUP BY cust
                     HAVING max(sufix)='000'
                  )
) 
WITH DATA
NOT LOGGED INITIALLY;

CREATE TABLE zorderHst AS 
( SELECT * 
    FROM orderHistory
    WHERE cust IN (SELECT cust 
                     FROM zaddresses
                  )
)
WITH DATA
NOT LOGGED INITIALLY;
```

There, you've defined your holding table and populated it in one single statement each.  It does have some nested logic, but nonetheless only two statements.

To purge them

```
DELETE FROM addressfile
  WHERE cust IN (SELECT cust FROM zaddresses);

DELETE FROM orderHistory
  WHERE cust IN (SELECT cust FROM zaddresses);
```

A grand total of four SQL statements.  (I wont even ask how many you'd have in your RPG program)

Once you understand SQL, you can think about processing entire files, not just record by record instructions.  It's **much** simpler to get things done, *and* it's almost always faster when done well.

(You may hear arguments about performance under particular circumstances, but most often they simply aren't using SQL as well as they should.  If you write poor RPG, it performs badly too. ;-)

Comment: ok this looks pretty nice. Actually I have a resource I can use for the sql part. just 1 question when you have here "WHERE cust IN (SELECT cust 
                     FROM orderHistory
                     GROUP BY cust"
                     HAVING max(sufix)='000'
                  ) this means that all such records for this customer number in the orderhistory are all = 000 ? this idea looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Except that this does not create your order history backup.

Comment: @Booksman Yes.  A WHERE clause filters records up-front deciding whether to include them for consideration before any other processing is done on them.  A HAVING clause filters data that resulted from the GROUP BY clause.  So `HAVING max(sufix)='000'` means that after all rows are examined for a customer group, that the greatest value is '000', or in other words no rows were found for the customer that were greater than '000'.  The `WHERE cust IN`  *subquery* `)` says the customer must be in the set returned by the subquery, which is the set of customers that do not have a suffix >  '000'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL.

```
-- Save only the rows to be deleted
CREATE TABLE ZADDRESSFILE AS
   (SELECT *
    FROM   ADDRESSFILE af
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM ADDRESSFILE sub
         WHERE sub.CUSTNO = af.CUSTNO
         AND   sub.SUFFIX <> '000' -- (or <> 0 if numeric)
         )
    )

-- If ZADDRESSFILE exists and you want to add the rows 
-- to ZADDRESSFILE instead....
INSERT INTO ZADDRESSFILE
   (SELECT *
    FROM   ADDRESSFILE af
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM ADDRESSFILE sub
         WHERE sub.CUSTNO = af.CUSTNO
         AND   sub.SUFFIX <> '000' -- (or <> 0 if numeric)
         )
    AND OT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM ZADDRESSFILE sub
          WHERE sub.CUSTNO = af.CUSTNO
          )
    )


-- Get number of rows to be deleted
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ADDRESSFILE af
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM   ADDRESSFILE sub
    WHERE  sub.CUSTNO = af.CUSTNO
    AND    sub.SUFIX <> '000'
    )


-- Delete 'em
DELETE
FROM ADDRESSFILE af
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM   ADDRESSFILE sub
    WHERE  sub.CUSTNO = af.CUSTNO
    AND    sub.SUFIX <> '000'
    )
```

Comment: It won't quite work this way, because the sufix is in the order history file, not the address file.